# How to replicate aggregate() functionality with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I'm trying to replicate the `aggregate()` base function with `data.table` syntax in this particular scenario:

```
# make it reproducible
set.seed(16)

# create data.table
DT <- data.table(source = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), target = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE))
#     source target
#  1:      j      J
#  2:      d      K
#  3:      w      L
#  4:      g      J
#  ...

# aggregate using base function
aggregate(list(target = DT$target), by = list(source = DT$source), FUN = function(x) paste(x, sep = ", "))
#   source              target
#1       a          L, W, S, W
#2       b V, H, R, J, G, W, N
#3       c          Y, C, I, K
#4       d          K, A, P, V
# ...
```

I tried a couple of things using the data.table syntax but I didn't get it to work:

```
DT[, .(target = paste(target, sep = ", ")), by = source]
#     source target
#  1:      r      P
#  2:      r      I
#  3:      r      Y
#  4:      r      G
#  ...

DT[, target := paste(target, sep = ", "), by = source]
#     source target
#  1:      r      P
#  2:      g      C
#  3:      l      U
#  4:      f      J
#  ...
```

What's the right way to do this?

Bonus points: remove duplicate `LETTERS` in output (i.e.: row 1 should be `L, W, S`, not `L, W, S, W`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to get a single string of all the elements in 'target' for each 'source', use `collapse` argument in `paste`.  This can be written more compactly using `toString` (which is `paste(..., collapse=", ")`)

```
DT[, .(target = toString(target)), by = source]
```

Instead of `paste`ing into a string, we can also have a `list` column

```
DT[, .(target = list(target)), by = source]
```

which will be similar to the `aggregate` output in OP's post (though the intention seems to be different with `paste`)

#### Update

If we need only unique elements, use the `unique`

```
DT[, .(target = toString(unique(target))), by = source]

DT[, .(target = list(unique(target))), by = source]
```

Also, if we need to `sort`, wrap it with `sort`

```
DT[, .(target = toString(sort(unique(target)))), by = source]
```

---

In the OP's `aggregate` code, the `sep` is not collapsing the string into a single one, instead what we get is a `list` column

```
str(aggregate(list(target = DT$target), by = list(source = DT$source), 
         FUN = function(x) paste(x, sep = ", ")))
#'data.frame':   25 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ source: chr  "b" "c" "d" "e" ...
# $ target:List of 25
#  ..$ 01: chr  "U" "Q" "G" "C" ...
#  ..$ 02: chr  "D" "S" "G" "W"
#  ..$ 03: chr  "R" "U" "L"
#  ...
#  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to only have unique `LETTERS` in the output? E.g.: row 2 should be `C, G, Y, S` and not `C, G, Y, S, S`.

Comment: @enricoferrero  Updated the post